# Kinesis Firehose with Elastic Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-kinesis

I have a use case where I want to insert data into elastic search domains. And I am using kinesis firehose that. I am not getting how does kinesis firehose insert data into elastic search domain? Does it use bulk insertion or one by one insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinesis Firehose batches your data.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html#frequency):

> The frequency of data delivery to Amazon ES is determined by the
> Elasticsearch Buffer size and Buffer interval values that you
> configured for your delivery stream. Kinesis Data Firehose buffers
> incoming data before delivering it to Amazon ES. You can configure the
> values for Elasticsearch Buffer size (1–100 MB) or Buffer interval
> (60–900 seconds), and the condition satisfied first triggers data
> delivery to Amazon ES.